# jQuery Datepicker being covered up by other page elements - z-index?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am having issues on my WordPress website with a jQuery Datepicker being covered up by the Visual Composer rule directly below it. I believe it is an issue with `z-index` but the CSS I am adding has no effect.

URL is **himelhochbb.com**

Adjust the window width down to mobile so you can experience the issue where the row right below it covers up half of the month Datepicker.

[image: See Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve], also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of DIVs that act like sections (I will call them "sections" just so I have a term to use). They all have data attributes like `data-vc-full-width="true"`.  Anything that is **within** one of those sections will not overlay another section DIV structure -- but something that is equal to those DIVs (i.e. a sibling) can overlay them. So, move the jQueryUI calendar out of the section div and make it a sibling (same level).

The rule you are bumping up against is: an child element **inside** container A cannot overlay container B, where A and B are siblings.